# How can i block certain views depending on active perspective?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I would like to be able to minimize,resize or even close views and then when i feel like it restore them them back in the perspective from say a menu.

A concrete example:
I have views V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,V6,V7 and perspectives P1,P2,P3. 
If i switch to perspective P1, views V1 and V2 show up but if i want i can also open V4, the rest of the views being unavailable.
If i switch to perspective P2, views V3 and V5 show up but if i want i can also open V4 and V6, the rest of the views being unavailable.
If i switch to perspective P3, views V1 and V3 show up but if i want i can also open V4,V6 and V7, the rest of the views being unavailable.
So depending on which perspective is active  i can only access a certain group of views

Any suggestions on how i could and should  do this?

Thank you guys

LE: BTW i want to do this programatically so that i may implement these rules in an app

Answer (score 1):

Just create custom perspectives: http://www.newyyz.com/ntgsite/tag/custom-perspective/

Then you can have as many perspectives as you want, tailored with the views you want in them.

Comment: well the thing is i want to do it using java code,because i want to make my own app. But, that aside, in your solution if i create my own perspective i  still can access all the views.

Comment: That's the way Eclipse as a platform works.  Even if you distribute a heavily customized RCP app using Eclipse, there's not really that much preventing end users from accessing views or installing other software in the platform.

Answer (score 1):

You *should not* try to forbid the creation of other views in those perspectives. Exactly that is what makes Eclipse a good customizable tool for every user. *You* surely don't know what views *I* as a user really need, you can only guess and create some good default perspectives.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what [@Bananeweizen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/44089/bananeweizen) mentioned, you can create fixed perspectives.  They prevent the user from opening other views while in that perspective.  It's just by default, you have to choose between allowing the user to open any view **or** providing them with a fixed set of views.

There's no preViewOpen event that you can veto.  You could add a part listener and when a part opens that you don't want, schedule a `UIJob` to hide that part ... but the user will see flicker in that case.

Comment: And I think that even for fixed perspectives, he will be able to save a copy of that perspective and modify it, or not?

Comment: oh ... there are properties to prevent the Open Perspective button from showing up, like `org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPreferenceConstants.SHOW_OPEN_ON_PERSPECTIVE_BAR`.  Even if the user can copy the perspective, though, it would still be fixed and they wouldn't be able to change it.